# java - JAXB Null value

Tags: java, xml, netbeans, jaxb

Maybe this is a simple request, but I haven't found the way to do it.

I have to build an XML output like these one:

```
 <person name="Mike">
    <orders id="1">
       <order ido="1"></order>
    </orders>
 </person>
```

I have to get the values from a query in the db, but in the case that the querys returns no "orders" then the XML have to be like this:

```
<person name="Mike">
    </orders>
<person>
```

Is these possible?, I know is kind of strange but is a requirement of the client.

Comment: " </orders>" by itself not valid XML.  Do you mane "<orders/>"?

Comment: And, in any case, "<orders/>" will most likely be interpreted/read by any parser exactly the same as if the orders element was missing altogether.  Parsers don't have options in this regard, they have to follow the XML specification (which defines not just the format of XML documents, but how XML content should be interpreted).

Comment: yeah, that's why i'm telling is strange but after a long talk with the client they saw that it was a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know we have this case in our code often.  We define the XML first as an XSD, and then generate the JAXB.  To do so, the orders would be 0..1, and then the list inside orders would be 1..n.

If you are just annotating your classes, I think you need to do something like this:

```
@XmlElement(name = "orders")
protected List<Order> orders;

public List<Order> getOrders() {
    if (orders == null) {
        orders = new ArrayList<Order>();
    }
    return this.orders;
}
```

This will always return a list.  If the list is empty, you should get <orders /> returned.

Answer (score 0):

You could set an empty instance of `Orders` on the `Person` class before marshalling to get the desired output.